# Защита от CSRF посредством токенов

Tags: csrf

Всем добрый день, читал много про csrf и то, что для защиты от этой атаки советуют использовать токены:
https://learn.javascript.ru/csrf , Википедия и пр.

Но в чем защита? Если пользователь залогинен в комплекс, скажем интернет банкинг, а суть CSRF именно в залогиненном комплексе. Что мешает получить нужную форму интернет банкинга, вытянуть из нее нужный Anti-CSRF токен?

**Пример кода:**

```
<form action="http://localhost/csrf/" method="GET">
    New password:<br />
    <input type="password" AUTOCOMPLETE="off" name="password_new"><br />
    Confirm new password:<br />
    <input type="password" AUTOCOMPLETE="off" name="password_conf"><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Change" name="Change">
    <input type="hidden" name='user_token' value='' />
</form>

<div id="token" style="display:none"><div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://bank.com/", false);    
    xmlhttp.send();

    var token = document.getElementById("token");
    token.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    tokens = document.getElementsByName('user_token');
    tokens[0].value = tokens[1].value;
</script>
```

**В чем тогда заключается защита посредством токена?**

Какие другие способы защиты вы знаете?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы не сможете сделать такой запрос через Javascript, т.к. браузер запрещает доступ на сторонний ресурс посредством Ajax.

Кросс-доменные запросы проходят специальный контроль безопасности, цель которого – **не дать злым хакерам** завоевать интернет.

Разработчики стандарта предусмотрели все заслоны, чтобы «хакер» не смог выполнить подобные действия.

[Подробнее о правиле ограничения домена (origin policy)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснение.